# C UDP Socket, include a 0x00 inside the data

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

Experimenting a bit with Linux C UDP programming.

Trying to query a game server to get current status.

What needs to be done:

First send a fixed message to the server.
The server replies with a message including a challenge value.
Send the original message but also include the challenge value.

I have got this to work in a very crude code, however, the protocol needs me to include null (0x00) in the middle of the data of the packet.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv){
 
 
  char *ip = "192.168.1.183";
  int port = 27015;
 
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  char buffer[1024];
  char concbuf[1024];
  char challenge[10];
  socklen_t addr_size;
 
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  memset(&addr, '\0', sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
 
  
  //Send this message to get a reply with a challenge value:
  bzero(buffer, 1024);
  strcpy(buffer, "ÿÿÿÿTSource Engine Query");
  sendto(sockfd, buffer, 25, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
  printf("[+]Data send: %s\n", buffer);
 

  //Recieve the challenge value:
  bzero(buffer, 1024);
  addr_size = sizeof(addr);
  recvfrom(sockfd, challenge, 9, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_size);
  printf("[+]Data recv: %s\n", challenge);


  //Add the challenge value and message together: 
  char* conchal;
  char* min4 = (challenge +5); //Remove the first 5 bytes, not wanted.
  printf("[+]Strip : %s\n",min4);
  conchal = malloc(strlen(min4)+25);
  strcpy(conchal,"ÿÿÿÿTSource Engine Query"); //Would like to add a 0x00 after this
  strcat(conchal,min4); //Concatenate the challange value and the message.
  
  sendto(sockfd, conchal, 29, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
  printf("[+]Data send: %s\n", conchal);
  //Works, however, no 0x00 between the message and the challenge, which is needed.

  //This should return server information
  bzero(buffer, 1024);
  addr_size = sizeof(addr);
  recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_size);
  printf("[+]Data recv: %s\n", buffer);

  


 
  return 0;
}
```

The thing i get stuck on is just that I need to have a 0x00 between the message and the challenge. What would the best way be to add that?
I have checked it with wireshark to confirm the error. Otherwise the packet is correct.

Side note: Yes, this is very crude, but I'm just in the experimenting phase.

Comment: If you need zeros in the middle of the array, then you can't use C string functions like `strcat`. The `memcpy` function can be used to append `challenge` to `conchal`, something like `memcpy(conchal + conchalLength + 1, challenge + 5, challengeLength - 5 + 1);` And of course you can't use `printf` to show the result, because `printf` is just going to stop when it finds that first zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got it to work with this! Hardcoded the lengths in just to see what was needed. Need to figure out a elegant way to calculate this. New concept for me and skipping the null termination is causing some extra loops for sure. However, thinking about it, hardcoded lenghts might still be valid as the server always need to reply in this fashion. If it does not, then its probably not a valid response any way.